# Windows 10 shuts down daily for no apparent reason

Tags: windows-10

My laptop shuts down everyday for no apparent reason. I bought the Acer V17 Nitro last summer. It was a show model running Windows 8; the last one on the shelf. I upgraded to Windows 10 as soon as it was released. Since then, the shut down happens everyday at around 9 pm. The shutdown times vary between 8 pm and 10 pm but sometimes even at 1 am or 11 am.

I checked the event log and found this:

```
The process C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.EXE (V17-NITRO) has initiated the shutdown 
of computer V17-NITRO on behalf of user V17-NITRO\Eigenaar for the following reason: 
No title for this reason could be found 
Reason Code: 0x800000ff 
Shutdown Type: shutdown 
Comment:
```

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Check the event log for events from User32 in Windows Logs > System. You should be able to see which application initiated the shutdown.

Comment: Where exactly in the event log though?

Comment: Click Start and type "event viewer", or press Windows + R and type "eventvwr"

Comment: Is it possible that you have set automatic updates for a specific time every day?

Comment: It could be, but when I looked at the updates yesterday. the last updates were installed on 14 January. How to disable update?

Comment: I just realized now that you asked where IN the event log, and not where IS the event log... Anyway, look in the folder mentioned in my original comment (Windows logs > System), and filter by source User32. It will tell you which application that initiated the shutdown.

Comment: Nice one! I found this: The process C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.EXE (V17-NITRO) has initiated the shutdown of computer V17-NITRO on behalf of user V17-NITRO\Eigenaar for the following reason: No title for this reason could be found
 Reason Code: 0x800000ff
 Shutdown Type: shutdown
 Comment:

Comment: The shutdown times vary between 20:00 and 22:00 but sometimes even at 1 AM or 11 AM.

Comment: Does it happen while you are using the computer, or only if it has been idle for some time?

Comment: Usually after idle for some time or when I walk away but sometimes I will just get a message saying windows is about to restart and then it just shuts itself down. Can't find the place to change the setting. In advanced Windows Updates settings, there is a drop-down option to Choose how updates are installed. There, I have selected 'Notify to schedule restart'. There are no option to stop the computer from restarting. Then again, the cause may be something else completely.

Comment: I would check the task scheduler as suggested by the original mike western in his answer.

Comment: Before the pc restarts itself, I do get a popup message saying: "You're about to be signed out. Windows will shut down in less than a minute." Warmer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Task Scheduler (from the Start menu start typing "Schedule" and a drop down will show two schedulers. Chose Schedule Tasks. When it launches expand the menu on the left side of the screen. You may see a Shutdown schedule. Right click it, and select Disable. This may have been entered by somebody at the store to have the machine shut down around closing time.

Comment: No there is no option called "Shutdown Schedule"

Comment: Right I think I found it. For those who are annoyed by random daily shutdowns, open Task Scheduler by hitting Windows button and typing in "Task Scheduler". Then from the left hand menu, select Task Scheduler (Local). Now check all the Active Tasks from in the right panel for a daily shutdown task.

Comment: omg, it was entirely my own fault. Thanks! On my Win 10 system the folder on the left was called called "Schedule Reboot".